# Checkbox lags in fragments if viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have a viewpager wherein I am inflating fragments (all fragments have same layout) which has a checkbox each in the xml. But the checkbox shows checked when I swipe on to the next fragment. I need to use a viewpager to show an even complex layout with a checkbox as fragment's heading and a recycler view as fragment's body. But all of it is laggy.
Below is my sample code (just an example which if get's solved I can hop on to my original task).
Any help would be appreciated.

***1. Main Activity***

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    public final static int PAGES = 5;
    // You can choose a bigger number for LOOPS, but you know, nobody will fling
    // more than 1000 times just in order to test your "infinite" ViewPager :D
    public final static int LOOPS = 1000;
    public final static int FIRST_PAGE = PAGES * LOOPS / 2;

    public MyPagerAdapter adapter;
    public ViewPager pager;
    MyFragment fragment;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myviewpager);



        adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(this, this.getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        pager.setPageTransformer(false, adapter);

        // Set current item to the middle page so we can fling to both
        // directions left and right
        pager.setCurrentItem(FIRST_PAGE);

        // Necessary or the pager will only have one extra page to show
        // make this at least however many pages you can see
        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

        // Set margin for pages as a negative number, so a part of next and
        // previous pages will be showed
        pager.setPageMargin(-30);
    }


}
```

***2. MyFragment***

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    CheckBox checkBox;


    public static Fragment newInstance(MainActivity context, int pos, float scale) {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("pos", pos);
        b.putFloat("scale", scale);
        return Fragment.instantiate(context, MyFragment.class.getName(), b);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mf, container, false);

        final int pos = this.getArguments().getInt("pos");
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("Jobi", "checkbox clicked");
                if (checkBox.isSelected() == true) {
                    checkBox.setTag(view.getTag(pos));
                    checkBox.setSelected(false);
                } else {
                    checkBox.setTag(view.getTag(pos));
                    checkBox.setSelected(true);

                }
            }
        });
        tv.setText("Position = " + pos);
        RelativeLayout relative_layout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
        relative_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("Jobi", " At Position " + pos);
            }
        });

        MyLinearLayout root = (MyLinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.root);
        float scale = this.getArguments().getFloat("scale");
        root.setScaleBoth(scale);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using setTag() getTag() here? do you have an array of CheckBox?

Comment: @BhavikMehta. Adding or removing setTag() isn't helping with what I require. This was suggested by a colleague.

Comment: See , there are a lot of things associated with your question, your code is quite easy and simple, but for me, there are a few questions, like, do you want to keep the checkbox state as it is even if fragments are swiped? your offscreenpagelimit plays a big role here, lets have a chat, so i can help you with this

Comment: Yes I'd like to keep to checkbox's state intact. Checked if it is checked and unchecked if it is unchecked.... If that's what you wanna know. I'd like to save the checkbox state.

Comment: What I require here is, the check should be visible when i've checked or selected it. But it gets checked when I swipe on to next or previous page.

Comment: So you have two ways to do it
1. Create a bean/model/pojo class which two params, int position and boolean isSelected and maintain an ArrayList<YourCustomClass> everywhere
2. Use SharedPreference, only if you have a fixed number of pages in viewpager or use a small SQLite table to hold the states of checkbox
The functionality is really very easy, it just sounds complex but its not

Comment: Found something working?

Comment: Hey! Sorry couldn't revert. But not really..It just does not seems like going anywhere close to working..

Comment: it could be working if you could have given a chance to me to resolve your issue

Comment: Well I'd really appreciate if it does. Let me know your email id and I can mail  you the sample project with a target gif. Hoping it works .